# Divide form submissions evenly between two email addresses

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I did search Stack Overflow to the best of my ability to make sure this has not been answered and I could not find anything.

I have a form on which you can select your nearest town, but in one specific town I have two branches.

Lets say... Cape Town has two branches across the street of each other... 
(cpt1@mail.com and cpt2@anothermail.com)

What I want to achieve is that If 10 people select cape town the emails should be send as follows:

```
cpt1
cpt2
cpt1
cpt2
cpt1
cpt2
cpt1
cpt2
cpt1
cpt2
```

Does this make sense?

I basically want 1 locations mail to be split between two branches, 1 for you, 1 for you, etc etc.

I was thinking of putting them in an array and then use a random number between 1 and 2 to select the mail from the array, but I want to know what would be best here as I actually have no clue.

My current code is as follow:

HTML:

```
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Contact Us</legend>

<!-- Name input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name Here" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- E-mail input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">E-mail</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail Here" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Town -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="town">Town</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="town" name="town" class="form-control">
      <option value="Cape Town">Cape Town</option>
      <option value="Bellville">Bellville</option>
      <option value="Pretoria">Pretoria</option>
      <option value="Johannesburg">Johannesburg</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Message -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="message">Message</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter Message Here"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
```

PHP:

```
$town = $_POST['town'];
switch ($town) {
    case 'capetown':
        $email_address = 'capetown@me.com';
        break;
    case 'bellville':
        $email_address = 'bellville@me.com';
        break;
    case 'pretoria':
       $email_address = 'pretoria@me.com';
        break;
    default:
       $email_address = 'headoffice@me.com';
}
mail($email_address, etc etc etc )
```

Comment: can u take 'city name' in case statement ?

Comment: Thank you for the message, I wish I could answer that? I am really new to php and programming in general.

Comment: i think u hv to take numbers there and assign different value number to city

Comment: In the HTML? I don't think so. That passes the value to the php which in this case is the town name.

I am looking for a way to manipulate that town name as a trigger to divide the form submissions between the two emails in that town.

Comment: jest check my answer for test  !

Comment: Just to clarify I do have this in I just leave it out here in order not to flood the question with lots of irreverent code   <form form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/phpincludes/mail.php">

Comment: You need some sort of database (or just a plain text file) where you'd store where the last email (related to the selected town) has been sent to. Without keeping record of that piece of information, there's no way to rotate addresses.

Comment: Now we are making progress I do capture everything is a DB regarding form data, however I am really not a pro here, would it be possible to guide me through a way to construct such a DB and a function to use said data? I would be so grateful

Comment: I see lots of people with the same issue but no answers no real help either.

https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/t...-email-address

http://www.tectite.com/vbforums/show...ission-Results

Answer (score 1):

html edited to:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="test.php" method="post">
 <select id="town" name="town" class="form-control">
      <option value="Cape Town">Cape Town</option>
      <option value="Bellville">Bellville</option>
      <option value="Pretoria">Pretoria</option>
      <option value="Johannesburg">Johannesburg</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

php edited to:

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
               switch ($town) {
    case '2':
        $email_address = 'capetown@me.com';
        echo($email_address);
        break;
    case '3':
        $email_address = 'bellville@me.com';
         echo($email_address);
        break;
    case '4':
       $email_address = 'pretoria@me.com';   echo($email_address);
        break;
    default:
       $email_address = 'headoffice@me.com';    echo($email_address);
}
?>
```

this code will prove u information which email select when u select perticular city!

Comment: This is not correct weather I use numerals or the town spelled out wont make a difference.

Comment: If some one selects cape town it must send an email to cpt1@mail.com when another person selects cape town it must be send to cpt2@anotheremail.com and when someone selects cape town again the process repeats itself so it will go to cpt1@mail.com and when someone selects cape town again it will go to cpt2@anotheremail.com and repeat thus ensuring both branches receives and equal chance to receive leads destines for Cape town

Comment: did u  use  <form action="test.php" method="post">  ?

Comment: Read through my code please, before you answer again. You are missing the entire point you will see I only added the fieldset part onswards. The form is working perfectly  <form form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/phpincludes/mail.php">

Comment: u dont hve form tag in your form  and my code working properly

Comment: You don't know what the question is thanks for your help but I'm afraid you don't have a clue what's going on (: